# StencilJs fails running dev server Error: write EPIPE

Tags: node.js, npm, stenciljs

I'm trying to develop a UI component library with StencilJs. Unfortunately as soon as i start the development server with the command `stencil build --dev --watch --serve --debug` it returns this error:

#### Error

```bash
> test-stencil@0.0.1 start C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil
> stencil build --dev --watch --serve --debug

[12:17.1]  @stencil/core
[12:17.3]  v2.17.3
[12:17.3]  node 14.20.0  MEM: 56.1MB
[12:17.3]  windows, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz  MEM: 56.1MB
[12:17.3]  cpus: 12, freemem: 22793MB, totalmem: 34105MB  MEM: 56.1MB
[12:17.3]  compiler: C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil\node_modules\@stencil\core\compiler\stencil.js
           MEM: 56.1MB
[12:17.3]  build: 20220802224219  MEM: 56.2MB
[12:17.4]  cache enabled, cacheDir: C:/Users/work/Desktop/test-stencil/.stencil  MEM: 60.1MB
[12:17.5]  create workers, maxWorkers: 7  MEM: 60.5MB
[12:17.5]  starting dev server ...  MEM: 60.5MB
[12:17.7]  dev server started: http://localhost:3333/ in 210 ms  MEM: 60.6MB
[12:17.7]  Starting compilation in watch mode...  MEM: 60.8MB
[12:20.1]  build, test-stencil, dev mode, started ...
[12:20.1]  start build, 2022-08-09T11:12:20  MEM: 173.0MB
[12:20.1]  [0] cleaning 4 dirs ...  MEM: 173.0MB
[12:20.1]  close watch  MEM: 173.1MB
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at ChildProcess.target._send (internal/child_process.js:863:20)
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:734:19)
    at receiveFromMain (C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil\node_modules\@stencil\core\dev-server\index.js:48:27)
    at Object.emit [as callback] (C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil\node_modules\@stencil\core\dev-server\index.js:142:17)
    at Object.emit (C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil\node_modules\@stencil\core\compiler\stencil.js:2031:14)
    at BuildContext.start (C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil\node_modules\@stencil\core\compiler\stencil.js:13787:29)
    at onBuild (C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil\node_modules\@stencil\core\compiler\stencil.js:64504:14)
    at Object.tsWatchHost.afterProgramCreate (C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil\node_modules\@stencil\core\compiler\stencil.js:64352:11)
    at Z (C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil\node_modules\@stencil\core\compiler\stencil.js:8913:2292225)
    at Object.e.createWatchProgram (C:\Users\work\Desktop\test-stencil\node_modules\@stencil\core\compiler\stencil.js:8913:2290238)      
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at internal/child_process.js:867:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  errno: -4047,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-stencil@0.0.1 start: `stencil build --dev --watch --serve --debug`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test-stencil@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-09T11_12_20_213Z-debug.log
```

> node version: v16.16.0 
> npm version: 8.11.0 
> OS: Windows 10

The strange thing is that it happens only on my computer, therefore I think it's a problem with some permission or settings that are misconfigured on my machine, but I have no idea where to look.

I have already tried to reinstall and downgrade node and use admin privileges on the shell where I execute the command,but no luck so far.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does adding `--verbose --no-cache` change anything? And does `npm run build` work?

Comment: Hi Thomas. `stencil build --dev --watch --serve --debug --verbose --no-cache`  produces the same error, but npm run build works just fine. I Tried other flags combinations and the problem appears whenever `--watch` and `--serve` are present

Comment: What about watch without serve and serve without watch?

Comment: if they are not together the command works. so `stencil build --dev  --serve --debug --verbose` and `stencil build --dev --watch  --debug --verbose` both work. But in the first case, the server terminates immediately after building and in the second, the build process is triggered every time i make a change (as expected).

Comment: Then a workaround would be not using `--serve` and manually run a server in the `www` directory, e.g. with [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Comment: Not The best developer experience, but a very good advice. Thank you